# Why fortran in vim keeps automatically line break

Tags: vim, fortran

I know that fortran has a column limit and I appreciate that in it can automatically start a new line when I exceed 72 columns. But this is not always what I want because most of the time I exceed the limit is because I am writing a comment, I don't want to start a new line for comments. I am new to vim and using yadr and not sure which plugin is doing this. My plugins are:

```
AnsiEsc.vim
AutoTag
IndexedSearch
LaTeX-Box
NrrwRgn
ag.vim
argtextobj.vim
base16-vim
camelcasemotion
change-inside-surroundings.vim
closetag.vim
color_highlight
compilergfortran.vim
compilerifort.vim
csapprox
ctrlp.vim
ctrlr.vim
delimitMate
file-line
fortran_codecomplete.vim
gist-vim
gitv
greplace.vim
gruvbox
gundo.vim
investigate.vim
lastpos.vim
lightline.vim
list.txt
matchit.zip
neocomplete
nerdcommenter
nerdtree
pyflakes-vim
rspec.vim
showmarks
splitjoin.vim
sudo.vim
supertab
syntastic
tabular
tcomment_vim
textobj-word-column.vim
tlib_vim
tmux.vim
vim-abolish
vim-addon-mw-utils
vim-bundler
vim-change-hash-syntax
vim-colors-solarized
vim-easymotion
vim-endwise
vim-flavored-markdown
vim-fugitive
vim-gfortran-compiler
vim-git
vim-html-escape
vim-indent-guides
vim-indentobject
vim-iterm-rspec
vim-latex
vim-markdown-preview
vim-misc
vim-multiple-cursors
vim-nerdtree-tabs
vim-polyglot
vim-r-plugin
vim-ragtag
vim-rails
vim-rake
vim-repeat
vim-ruby
vim-ruby-refactoring
vim-rvm
vim-session
vim-sneak
vim-snipmate
vim-snippets
vim-spec-finder
vim-surround
vim-tex-fold
vim-texlog
vim-textobj-datetime
vim-textobj-entire
vim-textobj-function
vim-textobj-function-javascript
vim-textobj-rubyblock
vim-textobj-rubysymbol
vim-textobj-underscore
vim-textobj-user
vim-tmux-navigator
vim-unimpaired
vim-visual-star-search
vimtex
vundle
webapi-vim
```

Can someone tell me which plugin is doing this and how to fix this?

Comment: The provided answers look good to me. But if they're not what you're looking for, it would help to post your `~/.vimrc` file.

Comment: If you are new to Vim,then don't use 50 plugins. It's more likely to confuse you (as you are now) than help you. Learn the basics first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't confuse wrapping with line breaking.

`:set wrap` breaks the line only visually, it actually is stil the one line. To disable use `:set nowrap`.

If it actually breaks the lines, adding a newline not only visually try:

```
set textwidth=0 wrapmargin=0
```

Answer (score 1):

In vim, you can use the `tw` option. For example

```
:set tw=120
```

sets the line width to 120 characters instead of 72.

If you just want to write a comment block, you can use

```
:set paste
```

so that no formatting will occur. To go back to formating mode, use

```
:set nopaste
```

This option is very useful if you want to copy/paste and don't want to be annoyed by auto-indenting.